# Why am I getting an error when I try to do a bulk update in the Workfront API?

Tags: workfront-api

I am trying to do a bulk update of a user:

```
/attask/api/v9.0/user/5c74714a01438ddef4262ca7d2b589a3?&method=PUT&updates=[{"ID":"5c74714a01438ddef4262ca7d2b589a3","name":"ChefSkyFoxWasHere","homeTeamID":"5ebee6d202125cdad1a6914f47328cd1"}]&apiKey=xxxxxxxx
```

but keep getting this message

```
{"error":{"message":"For bulk edits, the id of each object must be in the updates JSON"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. It was bad syntax:
/attask/api/v9.0/user/5c74714a01438ddef4262ca7d2b589a3/?updates={name:"ChefSkyFoxWasHere",homeTeamID:"5ebee6d202125cdad1a6914f47328cd1"}&method=PUT&apiKey=xxxxxxxx